# How are javascript class names calculated for custom classes in Chrome Dev Tools?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, google-closure-compiler

I am trying to determine the rules for generating class names in javascript.  I pasted this script into Chrome dev tools console:

```
var obj = { 
    Constr : function() {  }
};

var obj2 = obj;
console.log(new obj.Constr());
console.log(new obj2.Constr());

obj2.Constr2 = function() {  };
console.log(new obj.Constr2());
console.log(new obj2.Constr2());
```

And here are the results in the console:

```
obj.Constr
obj.Constr
obj2.Constr2
obj2.Constr2
```

It seems that the name of the class is determined by the variable that the constructor function was originally assigned to.  I am looking for the precise rules that CDT uses to generate this name.  Also, is this the same name that the Google Closure Compiler recognizes?

I have tried to see if I can reproduce similar behavior in Firebug, but I can't seem to get class names to print out in the console.  As a secondary question, does anyone know how to see this in firebug?

Answer (score 3):

There are no classes in Javascript, as it is prototype-based OOP, not class-based. Chrome apparently does some deducing in order to print some description of the object in the console, but that is not standard Javascript — in the standard, objects have no named class, and you cannot figure out the name of the class the object belongs to, since the only inheritance is done through the actual `[[Prototype]]` internal pseudo-property, which is also an object in its own right, with no name or "class". Usually, you might deduce something similar to a class name by looking at `object.__proto__.constructor.name`, which would return the name of the function which is the constructor from which the object was instantiated; *but* this function might be anonymous, *or* your browser might not support the non-standard `__proto__` property, *or* the prototype of the object might not contain a correct reference to its constructor. Generally, you cannot know the "class" of an object in JS; you can only test for descendancy (`object instanceof Constructor`), but that is still implemented according to the `constructor` property in the object prototype, which *might* be incorrect.

Comment: So, as I feared, the name printed out by CDT does not come from the ecmascript specs.  It is only a debugging convenience for the developer.  I am fairly new to Javascript and I generally like prototype style, but I find it disappointing that libraries like dojo and extjs try to shoehorn in OO style of programming.  I think that this muddles one of the better features of Javascript.

Comment: Javascript is a _very_ OO language, and is actually quite flexible in it. There are lots of libraries building a typical class-based OO _on top_ of Javascript, and that usually works quite well. This is not necessarily a bad thing for either those libraries or Javascript itself.