# Javascript e vs. object? Chome Inspector

Tags: javascript, object, google-chrome-devtools

I'm working on a small project with [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/), and trying to diagnose why using the map.load event is returning *Object [object Object] has no method 'load'* (although the load event is firing properly)

When I inspect the variable containing the map object in chrome instead of saying

*Object {foo: bar}*

it says

*e {foo: bar}*

What does the e represent? I can provide pictures of the chrome inspector output if that would help.

```
var map = L.map('map', {maxZoom: 16, minZoom: 4, zoomControl: false})
.setView([46.5675115, 17.468262], 6);
map.load(mapInit());

function mapInit() {
  console.log('Ive loaded');
}
```

Comment: `e` is the constructor. It is more useful when you use the uncompressed source.

Comment: could you (or anyone) elaborate on this slightly and put it into an answer?

Comment: Pretty sure this has been done before, see [How are javascript class names calculated for custom classes in Chrome Dev Tools?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12231139/1331430)

Answer (score 1):

`load` is an event, not a method. You need to use `on` to attach event listeners:

```
map.on('load', mapInit);
```