# Why this JS code is not valid?

Tags: javascript

Below code snipped throws an error `TypeError: myObj.prototype is undefined`. Could someone explain me why?

Why there is no `prototype` for `new Object()` & object literals as specified below?

```
var myObj = {
    a : "This is a",
    b : "This is b"
}

myObj.prototype.c= "This is c";  // TypeError: myObj.prototype is undefined
```

If this is not valid approach then how can I achieve this?

Comment: It should just be `myObj.c = "foo";`

Comment: You can get the prototype from an instance with Object.getPrototypeOf : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf although in this case you probably wouldn't want to.

Comment: Have a look at [Eloquent Javascript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter8.html).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In earlier versions of EcmaScript you could not directly access the prototype of objects; the `prototype` property existed only on functions, and it comes into play when they are used as constructors. So you could do this:

```
// This is the myObj constuctor
function myObj() {
    this.a = "This is a";
    this.b = "This is b";
}

// Setting a property on the constructor prototype
// All instances will share this
myObj.prototype.c= "This is c";

// Creating a new object and testing its "c" property
var obj = new myObj();
alert(obj.c); // "This is c"
```

[Modern browsers](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/#Object.getPrototypeOf) implement `Object.getPrototypeOf`, which means you can do this:

```
var myObj = {
    a : "This is a",
    b : "This is b"
}

Object.getPrototypeOf(myObj).c= "This is c";
```

**However, you have to be careful!** If you do this, then *all* objects that exist now and all objects that get created in the future will inherit the property `c` through their prototype chain!

This is because `myObj` is of type `Object`, and the prototype of `Object` is inherited by everything that is an object of *any* type. This leads to:

```
var myObj = {
    a : "This is a",
    b : "This is b"
}

Object.getPrototypeOf(myObj).c= "This is c";

var anotherObject = {};

alert(anotherObject.c); // "This is c" -- was it expected?
```

**[See it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/3XMBR/)**.

Comment: No! "x.prototype" is NOT "the prototype of x".

Comment: @thg435: I 'm not sure I understand your point, can you please clarify?

Comment: Sure -- when you write "someObj.prototype" in javascript you do not access the prototype of the object. `x.prototype` is completely different from the actual prototype of x - it just happens to have a confusing name.

Comment: @thg435: That assumes `someObj.prototype` exists for the "object". But `someObj.prototype` does not exist in general, only in the special case where `someObj` is a function. So where does that leave us?

Comment: I think this post explains the matter better: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16666302/989121 (the 2nd part)

Comment: @thg435: OK, I think I understand: you object to the passage *"...not directly access the prototype of objects; the `prototype` property existed...*" which seems to imply that the prototype of objects is what you access with `someFunction.prototype`. If this is it then I understand the objection, but I 'm not sure how to improve the wording.

Answer (score 1):

you should first declare a custom object like this:

```
function myObj(){
    this.a = "a";
    this.b = "b";
}
```

then you can add the "c" property to that object as follows

```
myObj.prototype.c = "c";
```

as you can see here http://jsfiddle.net/gwaqm/ the property c is successfully setted.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to add the c property after object creation you can do

```
myObj.c = 'This is c';
```

Answer (score 0):

Objects inherit the properties of the prototype of their constructor, not their own prototype.

You can use myObj.constructor.prototype. But you should not do that because ({ }).constructor == Object. So it you modify the prototype of that object you modify the prototype of all objects.

To create an object with a specific prototype use:

```
//New method
var proto = ...
var myObj = Object.create(proto);
```

**OR**

```
//Old method
var proto = ...
var constructor = function(){};
constructor.prototype = proto;
var myObj = new constructor();
```

**You should not** use `__proto__`, because it is bad design and "Non-standard" (See https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)
You can use Object.getPrototypeOf(obj) though

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the prototype of an Object via `prototype` - it would just be a property called prototype. You could access the prototype via `__proto__` (no ECMA-Standard!)

```
var myObj = {
    a : "This is a",
    b : "This is b"
}

myObj.__proto__.c= 3;

var test = {};

test.c //-> yields 3
```

The correct (standard compliant) way however would be to use either:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(myObj)
```

or

```
myObj.constructor.prototype
```

Comment: @Siva what's confusing about it?

Answer (score 0):

In your first example you used Object Literal Notation to define an object with two properties: `a` and `b`.

`prototype` is related to the `constructor` object. If you want to access the prototype of an object, you first start with a constructor function:

```
function myClass(){
  this.a = "This is a";
}
```

Then you refer to its prototype:

```
myClass.prototype.pa = "This is prototyped a";
```

Hence, all the objects that eventually share the myClass prototype will inherit the `pa` member.